# Autocomplete widget in CakePHP 3.X

Tags: php, cakephp, autocomplete, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to implement a form for students to signup in my website with an autocomplete control for *Schools*. For this purpose, I went to the **CakePHP 3.0** reference and found a [tutorial to achieve this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-inputs). My problem is that they don't explicitly say how to retrieve the data (in this case the array of school names) for the autocomplete and for that reason I can't make it work.
Here's my code:

register.ctp

```
<h1>Registration</h1><br>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'register', 'context' => ['validator' => 'registerValidator'], 'templates' => ['autocomplete' => '<input id="school" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>'])); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('fname', array('label' => 'First Name *', 'required' => true, 'placeholder' => 'First Name')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('sname', array('label' => 'Last Name *', 'required' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Last Name')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('country', array('options' => array('Select...', 'India', 'USA', 'Canada'), 'placeholder' => 'Select')); ?>
<?php //echo $this->Form->input('school', array('label' => 'School *', 'options' => array('Select...', 'School A', 'School B', 'School C'))); ?>
<?php
$this->Form->addWidget(
        'autocomplete', ['Autocomplete', 'App\View\Widget\Autocomplete']
);
$options = array("Arena", "Bambu", "Canela", "Perlita");
//echo $this->Form->input('School', ['type' => 'autocomplete']);
echo $this->Form->input('search', ['type' => 'autocomplete', 'label' => 'School *', 'id' => 'school', 'required' => true, 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'School']);
//echo $this->Form->autocomplete('search', $options);
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('province_region', array('label' => 'Province/Region', 'placeholder' => 'Province/Region')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('city_town', array('label' => 'City/Town', 'placeholder' => 'City/Town')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'E-mail *', 'required' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Email')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('birth_dt', ['type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Date of birth *', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 100, 'maxYear' => date('Y'), 'empty' => '-', 'default' => '', 'required' => true]);
?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Password *', 'required' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Password')); ?>

<?php
echo $this->Form->input('pwd_repeat', array('label' => 'Confirm Password *', 'type' => 'password', 'required' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Repeat Password'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Send');
?>
```

Autocomplete.php

```
   namespace App\View\Widget;

   use Cake\View\Widget\WidgetInterface;
   use Cake\View\Form\ContextInterface;

   class Autocomplete implements WidgetInterface {

protected $_templates;

public function __construct($templates) {
    $this->_templates = $templates;
}



public function render(array $data, ContextInterface $context) {
    $data += [
        'name' => '',
    ];
    return $this->_templates->format('autocomplete', [
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'attrs' => $this->_templates->formatAttributes($data, ['name'])
    ]);
}

public function secureFields(array $data) {
    // return [];
    return [$data['name']];
}

}

?>
```

UsersController.php

```
<?php



namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersController extends AppController {

public $helpers = [
    'Form' => [
        'widgets' => [
            'autocomplete' => ['App\View\Widget\Autocomplete']
        ]
    ]
];
....
```

And here's the output:

[image: Can't make it work!]

Any type of help will be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autocomplete` input will show you **only your earlier typed values using the same browser**.

> The autocomplete attribute specifies whether or not an input field should have autocomplete enabled.
>
> Autocomplete allows the browser to predict the value. When a user starts to type in a field, the browser should display options to fill in the field, **based on earlier typed values**.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

You want to show suggestions like search engines show. For retriving data you need to use javascript.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share the source so I can mark this question as answered?